# printf pathname on Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking for information on how to display with `getopts` a dirname without the basename.
This should give all the sh files in my computer first the basename, a tab character and then all
the directories.

For example if I do: `myBashfile.sh -e *sh`

I need to see as output:

```
test1.sh         /home/directory5/directory6
test60.sh        /home/directory50/directory6
anothertest.sh   /home/directory5/directory6
```

at the moment I have this:

```
while getopts b opt
 do
      case $opt in
        b) find / -name  $OPTARG -printf "%f\n"-print 2>/dev/null    ;;
       esac
done
```

which displays only this:

```
test1.sh
test60.sh
anothertest.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `-printf "%-20f %h"`?